# Is it reasonable to use .map inside a form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, array.prototype.map

I am trying to iterate n food products that all will have the same inputs, so whether or not the user will want X, Y, or Z elements to it.

I thought the idea was pretty good at the beginning, but I realized that the idea went to downhill when I couldn't control the inputs by id (validations) as the id is repeating itself in every iteration.

Here is my code of render()

```
<div className="modal-body modalFood" style={{ maxHeight: '400', overflowy: 'auto' }}>
              <div className="container">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="form">
                  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">


                    {food.map((product, index) => (

                      <li className="list-group-item2" key={product.idFood}>
                        //information about the food
                                Amount:
                              </label>
                              <input
                                value={amount}
                                type="number"
                                min="0"
                                max="999"
                                name="amount"
                                style={{ borderColor: '#001689' }}
                                autoComplete="off"
                                required
                              />
//more inputs

                     ))}
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                    </div>
                  </ul>
                </form>
              </div>
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or am I in the right track.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `key={product.idFood}`?

Comment: Oh true, I messed up while changing the variables right now. Let me update

Comment: Depending on what your validation function looks like (adding an `onChange={validateInput}` to the inputs for example), `map` is the right way to go. It returns a new array of "things" which React can use to update the DOM.